# Plotting 2D lattice data from c++ in Mathematica

Tags: c++, plot, wolfram-mathematica

I have a (probably stupid) question:

How can I plot D-lattice data generated by a c++ program in mathematica (9)?
(I'd think intuitively that this can not be too hard but with google, stackoverflow etc. I could not find any solution)

- What output format is best for this?
- Which mathematica command is best?

At the moment I am trying to give out the data in columns where each row is of the form:

```
xcoordinate ycoordinate value
```

I found out that one could in principle solve this by using MatrixPlot[] but for this one would have to provide the data in a matrix form which is incompatible with most other plotting programs so I want to avoid this if possible.

Comment: This question would be better suited to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Sry. I was not aware that something like this exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to StackOverflow and a little bit worried about the requirements for answers. I did my best:

From the facts given in the question, I can't see why not simply use `ListPlot3D`? You do not need any particular order in the dataset, Mathematica will try to sort your data.

First, you can export your C++ data into a file of the form

```
x1 y1 value1
x2 y2 value2
x3 y3 value3
...
```

A file of this format can be imported using

```
Import["path/to/file.txt", "Table"]
```

You will then have a matrix like in the following example:

```
d1 = Flatten[Table[{x, y, Cos[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]}, {x, 0, 6, 0.2}, {y, 0, 6, 0.2}], 1];
d2 = RandomSample[d1]
ListPlot3D[d1]
ListPlot3D[d2]
```

`d1` will be a flat list of `{x,y,z}`
`d2` will be the same list in shuffled form

Both will yield the same nice plot of a wave originating in `{0,0,1}`

As far as I can tell, `ListPlot3D` is available since Mathematica 8.